# Conditional import in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, video.js

I have a root instance that has several `CustomVideo`-components in it (amongst a bunch of other components). The `CustomVideo`-component implements [VideoJS](https://videojs.com/), but it's not on all pages that there is a `CustomVideo`-component, so I don't want to import VideoJS globally. Here is an example of components on a page:

```
App.js
|
|-- CustomVideo
|-- FooComponent
|-- CustomVideo
|-- BarComponent
|-- CustomVideo
```

In the top of CustomVideo, I import VideoJS, like so:

```js
import videojs from 'video.js';
import abLoopPlugin from 'videojs-abloop'


export default {
  name: "FeaturedVideoPlayer",
  props: {
    videoUrl: String
  }
  mounted() {
    let videoOptions = {
      sources: [
        {
          src: this.videoUrl,
          type: "video/mp4"
        }
      ],
      plugins: {
        abLoopPlugin: {
          'enabled': true
        }
      }
    };

    this.player = videojs(this.$refs.featuredVideoPlayer, videoOptions, function onPlayerReady() {});

  }
```

But if there are more than one `CustomVideo`, then I get a console warning:

> VIDEOJS: WARN: A plugin named "abLoopPlugin" already exists. You may want to avoid re-registering plugins!

I tried looking into conditional imports, but it doesn't seem like it's the way to do it.

---

Even if I try and import it in `app.js`, even though I would rather import it `CustomVideo`, then I get another console error:

**Attempt**

```js
import abLoopPlugin from 'videojs-abloop'
Vue.use( abLoopPlugin );
```

Then I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerPlugin' of undefined

---

How do I ensure that a plugin is registered only once?

Comment: Look into the instruction in [npm: videojs-abloop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-abloop), the plugin is one general javascript library, it is not one valid Vue plugin ([How to write one plugin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin). Try to use below codes in `app.js`. Example: `import videojs from 'video.js'    
import abLoopPlugin from 'videojs-abloop'
abLoopPlugin(window,videojs)` [Refer to Github: Videojs-abloop](https://github.com/phhu/videojs-abloop#example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Check `videojs.getPlugins().abLoopPlugin`

[`videojs.getPlugins()`](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/f6a66e62defc76bc63a15f244246f85ebb8fe321/src/js/plugin.js#L408) returns a symbol table of all loaded plugin names. You could simply check that `abLoopPlugin` is not in that table before loading it in your component:

```js
import videojs from 'video.js'

if (!videojs.getPlugins().abLoopPlugin) {
  abLoopPlugin(window, videojs)
}
```

#### Await `$nextTick` before using `ref`

You'll notice that your videos are initially not visible in your specified `<video>` element. This is because the `ref` is undefined when you pass it to `videojs` in `mounted()`.

The [`ref` docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) state:

> An important note about the ref registration timing: because the refs themselves are created as a result of the render function, you cannot access them on the initial render - they don’t exist yet!

The solution is to wait until the [`$nextTick()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick):

```js
async mounted() {
  // this.$refs.featuredVideoPlayer is undefined here
  await this.$nextTick()

  // this.$refs.featuredVideoPlayer is the <video> here
  this.player = videojs(this.$refs.featuredVideoPlayer)
}
```

[image: Edit Using videojs-abloop in Vue]

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. I still got the error, when I did what you suggested ( `if( !abLoopPlugin.loaded ) {` . When I console.logged `abLoopPlugin`, then I could see that it was a function (and therefore didn't have any `loaded`-property. But your answer got me to find the answer, which is to do this: ```if( ! videojs.getPlugins().abLoopPlugin ){ abLoopPlugin( window, videojs ); }``` . If you edit your answer to include this (and keep the nice comment on `nextTick`, then I'll mark your answer as the correct solution.

Comment: @Zeth Ah, I see that now that I log it. Updated answer and demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating instance of abLoopPlugin. I followed the same approach for vue-i18n and other plugins to use globally. Something like:

```
import AbLoopPlugin from 'videojs-abloop'

Vue.use(AbLoopPlugin) // CHECK IF REGISTER PLUGIN ERROR PERSIST

const abLoopPlugin = new AbLoopPlugin({
   ---your settings---
})
export default abLoopPlugin
```